# howler.js for multiple audio files

Tags: howler.js

It works for for a single file:

```
<button id="btn">Play</button>
<script>
 var btn = new Howl({urls: ['http://www.javascriptoo.com/application/html/btn.wav']})
document.getElementById('btn').onclick=function(){btn.play()}
</script>
```

But I need to play multiple files:

```
<button id="btn2">Play</button>
<button id="btn3">Play</button>
<button id="btn23">Play</button>
```

**Is it any easy way to solve it?**

Answer (score 4):

Either combine the different sounds into an audio sprite (recommended method):

```
var btns = new Howl({
  urls: ['http://www.javascriptoo.com/application/html/btn.wav'],
  sprite: {
    btn1: [0, 1000],
    btn2: [2000, 3000],
    btn3: [4000, 5000]
  }
});
```

Or, you can setup a new `Howl` for each button:

```
var btn1 = new Howl({
  urls: ['http://www.javascriptoo.com/application/html/btn1.wav']
});
document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = function(){
  btn1.play();
};

var btn2 = new Howl({
  urls: ['http://www.javascriptoo.com/application/html/btn2.wav']
});
document.getElementById('btn2').onclick = function(){
  btn2.play();
};

var btn3 = new Howl({
  urls: ['http://www.javascriptoo.com/application/html/btn3.wav']
});
document.getElementById('btn3').onclick = function(){
  btn3.play();
};
```